# I made a button on a wordpress header using custom css but I cannot change the color of the text on the button?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I am using the Ocean WP theme to build my website. I am also using the WP job manager plugin. On the header there is an option on the menu called "post a job" and I wanted to turn it into a button.

I found some information online and I managed to turn it into a button as so:
http://prntscr.com/pi6zec

I made some changes in the custom css section:
http://prntscr.com/pi70vb

But I want to change the color of the text to white so it can be seen more clearly next to the green. Does anybody know how I can change it?
I tried:

```
text-emphasis-color
```

and

```
text-decoration-color
```

...but they did not do anything, not that I could see anyway, does anyone know how I could change it?

Also, currently when I hover over the button it turns white and the text turns black, but it is only when I hover directly over the text that it allows me to click it. 
Is there a way I can change it so that if I hover anywhere inside the button I can click it, using css??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css is usually applied to the `a` link, which is within `#menu-item-840`. Basically, you are applying css to the container which gets bypassed by the css already applied on the content. This also explains why your padding is not clickable; you added green space to the container, not to the link inside it.

Instead of `#menu-item-840` try `#menu-item-840 a` , You can then change `#menu-item-840:hover` and `#menu-item-840:hover a` to a single `#menu-item-840 a:hover`

Comment: Ahh thanks benoitLussier, I'm not sure if I did it correctly but I changed it to:
https://prnt.sc/pi7b1i

and now when I hover over it the background of the text is highlighted white:
https://prnt.sc/pi7ahd

It was changing everything inside the border white previously: https://prnt.sc/pi7b7u

and still only lets me click on the word...

Comment: You didn't change "#menu-item-840" to "#menu-item-840 a" so your css is still applied to the container, not to the link itself.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot BenoitLussier, I misunderstood the first time but I have changed "#menu-item-840" to "#menu-item-840 a" and the button is now selectable when I hover anywhere in the button!!
 http://prntscr.com/pie2hz

Thanks again!!